# Is there any conceivable way that empty contracts that have ethereum in them could refund?

Tags: contract-development

So, about five days ago I accidentally sent a significant (At least to me) amount of Ethereum to an empty (No code "0x" smart contract)

I understand at this point in time it's locked away, there is no way to get that contract to transfer the funds.

But could an update to the Ethereum code for example, cause all contracts where this is the case to refund to the addresses that have sent Ethereum to them? I'm not the only one to have done this, check out this treasure chest for example:

https://etherscan.io/address/0xae7a1b1ba864696bcdcec94a34fb5836ca9a3910

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But could an update to the Ethereum code for example, cause all contracts where this is the case to refund to the addresses that have sent Ethereum to them?

Sure. An update to the Ethereum code, if accepted by the community, could do pretty much anything. This particular change would constitute a hard fork. I think it's unlikely that the community would go along with a change like that.